# Nix: Write a package that uses waf instead of make

Tags: build, nix, nixos, waf

## The question

I'm trying to write a package to install [libmonome](https://github.com/monome/libmonome), a toolkit for using the [monome](https://monome.org) hardware (OSC controllers with LEDs, mostly for music).

My efforts are based on these [instructions for building libmonome from source](https://monome.org/docs/serialosc/raspbian/). Note that those instructions use `waf`, not  `make`.

My [hello world](https://github.com/JeffreyBenjaminBrown/nixos-experiments/tree/c20581f839f8e0fb39b2762baeea7d0a7ab10783/custom-packages/) packages that use `make` build successfully. But my [`libmonome` package](https://github.com/JeffreyBenjaminBrown/nixos-experiments/tree/c20581f839f8e0fb39b2762baeea7d0a7ab10783/custom-packages/libmonome) that tries to use `python waf` analogously is not building:

```
[jeff@jbb-dell:~/nix/jbb-config/custom-packages/libmonome]$ nix-build 
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/kkf4c8l0njqdapnm2qgk6ffmybmafrpv-libmonome.drv
building '/nix/store/kkf4c8l0njqdapnm2qgk6ffmybmafrpv-libmonome.drv'...
Error: Cannot unpack waf lib into /nix/store/dk3pnwg7z9q14f4yj35y2kaqdmahnhhh-libmonome/.waf-2.0.17-6b308e91b5eb321c61bd5469cd6d43aa
Move waf in a writable directory
builder for '/nix/store/kkf4c8l0njqdapnm2qgk6ffmybmafrpv-libmonome.drv' failed with exit code 1
error: build of '/nix/store/kkf4c8l0njqdapnm2qgk6ffmybmafrpv-libmonome.drv' failed

[jeff@jbb-dell:~/nix/jbb-config/custom-packages/libmonome]$
```

## Some maybe-helpful, maybe-redundant information

If you're cloning the repo, note that you'll need to fetch submodules to get all the libmonome code. Here's one way to do that:

```sh
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/JeffreyBenjaminBrown/nixos-experiments
git checkout c20581f839f8e0fb39b2762baeea7d0a7ab10783
```

I already put absolute links to my code above, but in case you would rather see that code on this page, here is my `default.nix` file:

```
{...}:

with (import <nixpkgs> {});
derivation {
  name = "libmonome";
  builder = "${bash}/bin/bash";
  args = [ ./builder.sh ];
  buildInputs = [ git
                  coreutils
                  liblo
                  python2
                ];
  # I would like to use fetchGit but haven't gotten it to work.
  # src = fetchGit {
  #   url = "https://github.com/monome/libmonome.git";
  # };
  repo = ./libmonome;
  system = builtins.currentSystem;
}
```

and here is the `builder.sh` script it calls:

```sh
set -e # Exit the build on any error
unset PATH # because it's initially a non-existant path
for p in $buildInputs; do
  export PATH=$p/bin${PATH:+:}$PATH
done

cd $repo

# I've tried with python2 and python3
python2 ./waf configure
python2 ./waf
sudo python2 ./waf install
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/59809635/428586